# Login logout cache/ cookie Prestashop

Tags: php, .htaccess, cookies, prestashop

My Prestashop website has this cache/cookie issue I am not sure.

When customer login, then she clicks other pages, it will come back to login button again instead of Welcome xxx | Logout
And when he/she clicks log out, he/she still have Logout button like she never logged out but if you force refresh the website then it's updated.

I think it's PHP issue, so I added these few lines in my .htaccess file;

```
# Dispatcher
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.kdtrading.com.au$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.kdtrading.com.au$
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>

#If rewrite mod isn't enabled
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?controller=404


ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 0 days"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 minutes"

# Don't cache dynamic pages 
<filesMatch ".(php|cgi)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, private, no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>
```

But the problem still persists.

So I added this on my FrontController.php

```
if (isset($_GET['logout']) || ($this->context->customer->logged && Customer::isBanned($this->context->customer->id)))
        {
            header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
            $this->context->customer->logout();
            Tools::redirect(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : null);
        }
        elseif (isset($_GET['mylogout']))
        {
            header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
            $this->context->customer->mylogout();
            Tools::redirect(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : null);
        }
```

And it's still there.

Comment: Is it a clean install of prestashop or has it been customised in different area's? and what version of prestashop?

Comment: Hi @Trevor our website has been customised in some areas, the version is 1.5.4.1